# Started getting error 'Can't resolve all parameters for myApp' after importing Push

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

Greetings as the title suggests my issue is pretty straight forward, after i tried to import Push notifications, my '@Component({})' started giving me errors, when i hover over my injected constructor where i inserted my push import i get the following error "can't use namespace 'Push' as a type."

Here's a printscreen: https://i.stack.imgur.com/VcCTn.jpg

And another: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4tuo.jpg

And at last here's my code:

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { Push, PushObject, PushOptions } from '@ionic-native/push';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'app.html'
})
export class MyApp {
  rootPage:any = HomePage;

  constructor(platform: Platform, statusBar: StatusBar, splashScreen: SplashScreen, private push: Push) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      statusBar.styleDefault();
      splashScreen.hide();
      this.pushSetup();

    });
  }

  pushSetup(){
    const options: PushOptions = {
      android: {
        senderID: '781594090050'
      },
      ios: {
          alert: 'true',
          badge: true,
          sound: 'false'
      }
   };

    const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);


    pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

    pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

    pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
  }

}
```

app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { ErrorHandler, NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicApp, IonicErrorHandler, IonicModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar';

import { MyApp } from './app.component';
import { HomePage } from '../pages/home/home';
import { Push } from '@ionic-native/push';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(MyApp)
  ],
  bootstrap: [IonicApp],
  entryComponents: [
    MyApp,
    HomePage
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    Push,
    {provide: ErrorHandler, useClass: IonicErrorHandler}
  ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

How do i fix this? please help

Comment: after running these commands: `ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push` and `npm install @ionic-native/push`, have you tried to restart your `ionic serve` instance?

Comment: well observed, after re-installing both components it started to work, thanks a lot!

Comment: for future reference, i've posted an answer, glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the push plugin you have to run the following commands

```
ionic cordova plugin add phonegap-plugin-push
npm install @ionic-native/push
```

after running these commands restart your ionic serve instance